# Firebase - Is there a way to iterate through all documents in a collection, and find a certain value for a field within each of them

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, iteration

I am trying to find a way to iterate through each document in a collection, and find the value for a certain field each time for my Firebase Database in Node.js

Here is an example of a database structure that has the same structure as mine:

```
{
  "users": {
    "tommy": {
      "username": "tom",
      "points": 3
    },
    "bryan": {
      "username": "bry123",
      "points": 7
    }
  }
}
```

In this case,  I would want it to return the points for each users. Meaning the first time it would return 3, and the second time 7. I tried looking at the Firebase Documentation but couldn't find what I needed. Is anybody able to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure thing, something like this should do the trick:

```
let db = firebase.database().ref();
let usersRef = db.child("users");
users.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot) {
    console.log(userSnapshot.key); // "tommy", "bryan"
    console.log(userSnapshot.val()); // { "username": "tom", "points": 3 }, { "username": "bry123", "points": 7 }
    console.log(userSnapshot.child("points").val()); // 3, 7
  });
});
```

I highly recommend spending more time reading the Firebase documentation, some of the tutorials out there, and searching previous questions on the topic.

Comment: Thank you! I'll definitely take a closer look :)